# Upload Multiple images using AJAX (formdata), PHP, and Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, multipartform-data

I have questions about Upload Multiple images using AJAX (formdata), PHP, and save them into Project Folder and Mysql Database.
I have made a sample and so far have not found a definite answer.

Form HTML :

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="foto">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="foto">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="foto">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addImages()">Submit</button>                
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="resetForm()">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax Function :

```
function addImages() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var foto = $('#foto').val();

    if (foto !== '') {
        var file = $('#foto').prop('files')[0];
        var ext = foto.split('.').pop();
        ext = ext.toLocaleString().toLocaleLowerCase();
        if (ext !== 'png' && ext !== 'jpg' && ext !== 'jpeg') {
            swal("File yang diupload harus png, jpg atau jpeg");
            return false;
        }
        formData.append('file', file);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: getUrl() + "/imageupload",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            if (jQuery.trim(response) == true) {
                swal({title: "Succeed to upload images", type: "success", showCancelButton: false
                }, function () {
                    location.reload();
                });
            } else {
                swal({title: "Failed to upload images. ", type: "error", showCancelButton: false
                }, function () {
                    location.reload();
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

MySQL Query:

```
function insert_image($db = NULL, $data = array()) {
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO image_location (file) VALUES ('" . $data['foto'] . "')";
    $db->exec($SQL);
    $insert_id = $db->lastInsertId();
    return ($insert_id ? TRUE : FALSE);
}
```

**FYI**

I wrote in 2 different Files. File AJAX functions and HTML Form in one file while the process database is in a separate file that I have created a function like:

```
foreach (glob('../model/*.php') as $filename) {
include_once $filename; }
```

Thank's

Comment: Hi, I think you forgot your questions! is there any problem in your codes?

Comment: You are open to SQL injections and you should check the extension also server side.

Comment: @MohammedAlhanafi im sorry, i'm forget it. I have an error : When I click submit, it always fails. So, is there anything wrong with my code or want to add something

Comment: is your ajax request or php script showing any error ???